# Deploying and updating website

Tags: git, deployment, localhost

I prefer to put my projects in the localhost as `http://domain.local`

In addition, I use Git to push files to the remote server. The problem is that I don't want to edit the domain name on the server on each time the website is updated.

I don't think it is the right way to use `http://domain.com` in the localhost. What is the right way to overcome this issue?

To note, there are subdomains such as `images.domain.local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web frameworks store configuration for development setup and production server in separate files. Do not hardcode domain name and use such standard mechanism. You can choose between the configurations using git commit hooks, by reading machine hostname etc.

Answer (score 3):

Don't hardcode the domain, use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or whatever the equivalent is in your language/environment of choice to let your application dynamically figure out what domain it's running on.

Answer (score 1):

- As mentioned in comments you try to use as much relative path as possible.
- You should also try to have different environments (the production environment shouldn't be linked with your git master), deploying from git could be followed by a script that configure your production environment (look at phing if you want to have a state of the art process)
- If you still want to do something with your commit (or pull request from production) you can use git hooks http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks